# Plot complex self defined function with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals

I'm trying to plot a function with TikZ that behaves different for several cases. Therefore I use an \ifthenelse in the \def statement. Using such a definition a plot with TikZ does not work. However, simple functions without \ifthenelse are no problem. I have a minimal example to show this problem:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\simpleFunction(#1,#2){#1*#1}
\def\complexFunction(#1,#2){\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{0}}{0}{4}}

\begin{document}
\section{foo}

% definition of function correct and working
\complexFunction(0.005,0.00000003)
\complexFunction(0,0.00000003)

% simple function plot works
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm]
plot [domain=-200:200, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{\simpleFunction(\x/200,0.00000003)});
\end{tikzpicture}

% complex function plot does not work
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm]
plot [domain=-200:200, samples=100, smooth] (\x,{\complexFunction(\x/200,0.00000003)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I assume that the problem are the several brackets within my function definition. Does anyone know a solution for my problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure why the function fails when used in a plot, but I would define the function differently, using the `declare function` key:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\pgfkeys{
    /pgf/declare function={f(\a,\c) = (\a < \c) * 4 + !(\a < \c) * 3;}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [red, thick, x=0.0085cm, y=1cm]
plot [domain=-200:200, samples=100, const plot] (\x,{f(\x/200, 0)});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Conditional expressions in defining functions, learned something new. :)